# Display scrollbars on a java control that's passed to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, oop, jframe, awt

I'm creating a re-usable control that will be displayed in a JFrame. The control will have scrollbars on it. (The JFrame displaying this control will not.) When I pass this control to a JFrame for display, the control scrollbars are NEVER visible - even though I explicitly told the control to make them visible.

How do I make the scrollbars visible on a user control when it's being displayed in a JFrame? What am I missing?

This is the UserControl code:

```
public class TestUserControl extends JPanel {

    public TestUserControl(String greeting) {
        setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblTestLabel = new JLabel("This textbox will greet you.");
        lblTestLabel.setBounds(113, 12, 192, 15);
        lblTestLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        add(lblTestLabel);

        txtfTextField = new JTextField();
        txtfTextField.setBounds(66, 37, 303, 81);
        txtfTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        add(txtfTextField);
        txtfTextField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnOkButton = new JButton("OK");
        btnOkButton.setBounds(184, 130, 54, 25);
        add(btnOkButton);

        btnOkButton.addActionListener(new OkButtonClickManager());
        txtfTextField.setText(greeting);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);

        scrollPane.setSize(400, 250);
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the JFrame code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        TestUserControl testControl = new TestUserControl("Hello, Joe Smith.");
        testControl.setVisible(true);
        createGui(testControl, "Testing 1,2,3...");
    }

    private static void createGui(JPanel contents, String windowTitle) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(windowTitle);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowCloseManager());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a null layout!!!

The scrollbars will appear automatically when the `preferred size` of the panel is greater than the size of the scroll pane. The layout manager is responsible for determining the `preferred size` of the panel. Since you are NOT using a layout manager the preferred size is zero so the scroll bars do not appear.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks, Camickr.

I had to set a specific layout (BoxLayout was best). I also had to set the size of the scrollpane, but I never set the preferred size of the panel itself.

I appreciate it.